# onclick disable submit button

Tags: php, javascript

i wanna disable a submit button when onclick. im able to disable the button but i cant submit the post value to php.

Comment: You might want to show how you're disabling it. It's impossible to help you with the little information you've presented.

Comment: well looking at my previous questions posted, i cant seems to find good solid ans here. all i saw was people arguing on ajax vs iframe. so tell me wats there to feedback.

Comment: hi daniel, i will show my code below. feel free to comment it. tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a alternative online. wat i did is to create a fake disable and hidden button. when the actual button is clicked, i will hide it and show the fake disable button.

**actual button:**

```
$onclick = "
var boolconfirm = confirm('$strconfirmattempt');
if(boolconfirm==true){
finishattempt.style.display='none';
finishattempt2.style.display='inline';
}
return boolconfirm;";
```

**fake button:**

```
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"finishattempt\" value=\"submit\" onclick=\"$onclick\" />.
<input type=\"submit\" id=\"finishattempt2\" name=\"finishattempt2\" value=\"submit\" style=\"display:none;\" DISABLED/>\n";
```

Comment: Format your code better. It shouldn't be in an incomprehensible chunk like that. And once you've formatted it, highlight the code and hit `Ctrl+K`, which will indent everything by 4 spaces, causing it to be displayed as pre-formatted source-code.

Comment: +1 for finding a workable solution and formatting your code. Though in the future you might want to break the code into more lines so that the horizontal scrollbars don't appear. But as it is it's already 100x better than it looked before.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled = true" value="Save"/>
```

or ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545641/how-to-submit-form-only-once-after-multiple-clicking-on-submit)

Comment: hi, this works but if i wanan submit to php, the POST value is missing. however, i have found an alternative solution which i will post below. feel free to comment on it.

Answer (score 3):

If you disable an input, then its value naturally won't be included in the form data. You'll need to disable the button *after* you submit. If you bind a callback to `onclick`, then it runs *before* the form submits.

What you need is something like this:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).unload(function() {
        $('#submit-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

**Regular JS:**

```
document.onunload = disableSubmit;
function disableSubmit() {
    /* disable the submit button here */
}
```

Basically, instead of binding to the submit button's `onclick` event, this binds the disabling code to the document's unload event (`document.onunload`), which gets fired once the form is submitted and you begin to leave the page.

Comment: Add something about how your code is jQuery and not plain old JS

Comment: Ah, yea, I had mentioned that the first snippet was jQuery in one of my edits, but I think I accidentally deleted it.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with simple jQuery. The code removes the button on click, then appends the fake button or some like "loading.." text and finally sends the form.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="holder"><input type='submit' value='ACCEPT' class='button'></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.button').click(function() {
        $('.button').remove();
        $('.holder').append("//fake input button or whatever you want.");
        $('.form').submit();
    });
```

In diference with other methods like unload the button changes in the instant moment you click and sends the form. With heavy forms i think is a better practice.

Answer (score 2):

Using **jQuery**, add onClick handler that returns false:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="$(this).click(function() {return false;});"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hidden field which would hold the value of the button and pull that value out of your POST data:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="default" />

<input type="button" id="myButton" onclick="buttonClick();">

function buttonClick()
{
    document.myForm.myButton.disabled = true;
    document.myForm.hiddenField.value = "myButtonClicked";
}
```

My PHP is a little rusty, but then you can access the hidden field like so:

```
if ($POST['hiddenField'] == "myButtonClicked")
{
    // Click handling code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a disabled submit button that is hidden, and an active submit button, and onClick show the disabled and hide the active? I could do this in jQuery, but I'm kinda useless without it. Sad, eh?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using onsubmit instead of onlick:

This goes at the top:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function disableButtons()
{
  $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
}
</script>
```

Then your PHP (note that isset post is NOT for the submit button, because we want to disable the submit button).

```
if (isset($_POST['dothis'])) 
{
//CODE TO EXECUTE
}
```

Then HTML.

```
<form method='post' action='' onsubmit='disableButtons()'>
<input type='hidden' name='dothis' value=''>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>
```

Onsubmit goes in .
Make sure your isset (the PHP part) is for an input that goes with your submit, but is not the submit button itself. You can see that it is the hidden value being checked for with the PHP, rather than the submit button, and the submit button is what gets disabled. 
By doing this, you can disable a submit button without disabling the PHP.