# More submit button disabling on click with Jquery, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, get

I got this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186523/onclick-disable-submit-button):

It works fine as far as disabling and replacing the Submit button goes, but it will not submit the form. My form uses the 'get' method and submits data to another page.

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('.button').remove();
        $('.holder').append("DONT DOUBLE CLICK ANYTHING IN A BROWSER");
        $('.form').submit();
    });
    </script>
```

I have tried most things, including changing .form to the id of my form, still no joy, any ideas would be helpful.

HTML code

```
<form action="liftingConfirm.asp" method="get" id="frmArchiveConfirm">
<input name="con_id" type="hidden" id="con_id" value="<%=request.querystring("con_id")%>" />
<input name="sub_id" type="hidden" id="sub_id" value="1" />
<input name="liftingDate" type="hidden" id="liftingDate" value="<%=Session("currentUSDate")%>" />
<div class="holder"><input name="btnConfirm" type="submit" class="button" id="btnConfirm" value="Start New Lifting Gear Examination"  /></div>
```

Comment: post your html code here

Comment: Please **edit your question** and add your HTML code rather than using a comment

Comment: @TomWalters I did it for him :-)

Comment: It doesn't have a `class="form"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong selector, the `.form` is looking for a `<form>` with a class of `form`. Furthermore you should be using the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) syntax:

```
$('form').on('click', '.button', function() {
    $('.holder').append("DONT DOUBLE CLICK ANYTHING IN A BROWSER");
    $('#frmArchiveConfirm').submit();
    $('.button').remove();
});
```

Comment: so i need to tag the form with class="form" aswell?

Comment: No, the selector `form` selects all `<form>` elements, if you want to select only the form in your question you could use the ID selector `#frmArchiveConfirm`. [This article](http://sunali.com/2010/02/03/introduction-to-jquery-and-jquery-selectors/) is a good introduction to selectors and jQuery in general.

Comment: Thanks Tom, the form seems to do something (the egg timer now appears when i hit submit) but it only replaces the submit button, form tries to do something, then button re-appears)  I have checked the dbase the form isn't submitting the data. please note this submit path worked fine until I added code to try and stop double clicking.

Comment: Depending on what browser you're using, you should use the Inspector to trace calls made to the server (try right-clicking and selecting _Inspect Element_)

Comment: I have traced it, it's actually doing nothing, just reloading the same page.

Comment: [Let's continue this in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26008/jquery-submit-question)

Answer (score 0):

For your jQuery code to work you should include the `frmArchiveConfirm` to your jQuery code as below.

Replace `$('.form').submit();` with `$('#frmArchiveConfirm').submit();`

else if you only having one form in the page just use `$('form').submit();`

*When you come across bug like this don't forget to make use of the firebug or the browser development tools. You can easily figure out the bug and what's wrong in your code.*

Comment: i explained already in the original post i had tried that to no avail